# Tabulator "download visible rows to PDF" not working

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Hoping someone can help me with this one.  I'm using Tabulator to display data in a table and I added a button to download it to PDF.  I want it to only download the visible rows, not all rows, or all active rows (rows matching filter).  I'm using version 4.5 and according to the documentation found here:

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/download#dataset

It says that I should be able to add an optional fourth parameter to "table.download" passing in "visible" to only download the visible rows.  If I don't pass in anything, it downloads all active rows into the PDF, which is the default.  If I pass in "visible", it only downloads the 1st row, even though 25 rows are currently visible (paginationSize: 25).  See the three pertinent sections below:

```
<button id="download-pdf" class="button">Download PDF</button>
```

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        pagination: "local",
        paginationSize: 25,
        layout: "fitDataFill",
        printAsHtml: true,
        printCopyStyle: true,
        columns: [
            { title: "Field 1", field: "field_1" },
            { title: "Field 2", field: "field_2" },
            { title: "Field 3", field: "field_3" },
            { title: "Field 4", field: "field_4" },
            { title: "Field 5", field: "field_5" },
            { title: "Field 6", field: "field_6" },
            { title: "Field 7", field: "field_7" },
            { title: "Field 8", field: "field_8" },
            { title: "Field 9", field: "field_9" },
            { title: "Field 10", field: "field_10" },
            { title: "Field 11", field: "field_11", download: false, print: false },
            { title: "Field 12", field: "field_12" },
        ],
    });
```

```
$("#download-pdf").click(function () {
        table.download("pdf", "data.pdf", {
            orientation: "landscape",
            title: "Example Report",
        }, "visible");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug with an old version of Tabulator. this was fixed in the 4.7 release. if you update to the latest version of the library it should now work